# Class file errors when using onLongClick with setText

Tags: android, settext, onlongclicklistener

I created this little program to try and learn buttons and textviews. When attempting to use the onLongClick to setText, I get a force close. When I look at the debugger I see a nullpointerexception at line 45 holdMeAnswer.setText("Nope!");.

I see a whole bunch of "Class file error: Source not found" errors underneath the nullpointer. I've tried pointing the attached source to both the Java src.zip and the android.jar files but neither seems to fix anything.

Code is:

```
package com.PickSomeButtons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;

public class PickSomeButtons extends Activity {

    RadioButton myButton0;
    RadioButton myButton1;
    TextView myAnswer;
    TextView holdMeAnswer;
    Button longClickButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myButton0=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        myButton1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        myAnswer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        longClickButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        myButton0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAnswer.setText("Me!");                
            }
        });
        myButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAnswer.setText("Not me!");
            }
        });

        longClickButton.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                holdMeAnswer.setText("Nope!");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate method you initialize myAnswer but not holdMeAnswer. Thus holdMeAnswer is null.

You might try enabling more of the warnings in Eclipse under Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings. I think there might be a warning for uninitialized private members (as an aside, those members should probably be private).

Comment: Cool :) I realize I didn't answer your second problem but it appears to be irrelevant. You should only have to install the JDK and set up Eclipse to use the Android source as described on the Android Developers getting started site, and further steps are unnecessary unless you're trying to integrate some 3rd party API or create a project library.

Comment: Also if this answer satisfies the question, please check as correct. It will give both of us points and increases the chance of others answering your questions later. :)